# NSURLSession tasks run in for loop

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to use an `NSURLSession` to load multiple requests in a for loop.

```
for id in ids{
    // ids is an Array of String
    let url = NSURL(string:"http://example.com/something?ID=\(id)")   
    //                                                     ^ 
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){(data, response, error)in
        if error2 != nil {
            print(error2)
            return
        }
        do{
            let strjson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)

            // Here is the problem the for loop doesn't let enough time to the NSURLSession
        }catch let errorjson {
            print(errorjson)
        }
    }.resume 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't let enough time? You are aware that the network activity will happen asynchronously, so you need to process the data in the completion handler, not immediately after the loop

Comment: Your code appears well-formed. You have the code that processes the incoming data for each request in the completion handler, like you're supposed to do. At the "Here's the problem" comment in your code, the `strjson` string should contain your JSON data, or the catch clause could trigger if the call to `JSONObjectWithData` fails. Note that the different requests won't finish in a predictable order, and you don't have any logic to figure out when all the requests are completed.

Comment: @Paulw11 the problem is that the data that i get is not in order every time i run the code i get a new order :/

Comment: @DuncanC as I said the problem is that the data that i get is not in order every time i run the code i get a new order :/

Comment: Actually all you said was "I'm trying to load multiple NSURLSessions in a for loop.
". You gave no indication of what the problem was, until 7 minutes ago.

Comment: Async network requests take a variable, unpredictable amount of time. If you make multiple requests they will finish in an unpredictable order. If you need to handle the requests in a particular order you'll need to add logic that waits until they are all complete and then serves them up in the original request order.

Comment: Alternately you could post one request at a time, wait for it to complete, and then post the next one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one approach using Grand Central Dispatch:

```
let urls = ids.map { NSURL(string:"http://example.com/something?ID=\($0)")! }

let group = dispatch_group_create()

// Loop through the urls array, in parallel
dispatch_apply(urls.count, dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0)) { i in

    // Tell GCD that you are starting a new task
    dispatch_group_enter(group)

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urls[i]) { data, response, error in
        // Do your thing....

        // Tell GCD you are done with a task
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }.resume()
}

// Wait for all tasks to complete. Avoid calling this from the main thread!!!
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

// Now all your tasks have finished
```

Comment: Yeah, that's another way to make the requests run sequentially. It does mean that only one request will be in progress at a time